# How to unzip files that contain .DS_Store from a different computer?

Tags: macos, zip, osx-mountain-lion

I'm trying to unzip folders that contain .DS_Store files from another computer and because of this, i cannot unzip the folders. I keep getting the error:

```
Error - unable to expand into downloads (Error 2 - no such file or directory)
```

Anyone know how i can unzip these folders?

Comment: Is it a file that was compressed with Winzip?  What program are you using to decompress the archive?  Have you tried opening the archive with a different program (WinRar, 7zip, etc) and then manually expanding the archive into the location of your choice?

Comment: It was not compressed with Winzip. It's files that i'm trying to download via mozy.com web restore. I had a computer die and i'm using a new computer and i need the files on my new computer. I have not tried with anything other than the osx default unzipper

Comment: "because of this, i cannot unzip the folders" No, that's not why. There is a problem with the archive itself.

Comment: I'm not sure you're correct, because i can download folders from mozy web restore and unzip them no problem if they don't have a .DS_Store file in them

Comment: @Catfish: correlative, not causative. Presence of those files in the archive would not give that error.

Comment: Then if you're telling me the files are bad, why can i dig into a folder in mozy's web view and pull the files down individually and unzip them?

Comment: @Catfish he's telling you there's something wrong with the way Mozy is converting them into a zip archive. You can check the file at the OS X Terminal with `zip -sf -r /path/to/archive.zip` (if you don't know how to type in the path, you can drag the file from the Finder into the Terminal window and it'll paste in the path. Just be sure to include the space between `-r` and the dragged-in path).

Answer (score 0):

You could try a software like to BetterZip to view the archive and perhaps extract selectively the files you like.

Comment: Looking in the file with BetterZip shows that the files i'm expecting aren't there, but folders rather than files with the filenames that i would expect. The folders contain nothing so maybe it is an issue with mozy.